# Lazy load issue and JS menu query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a query that is JS related. the page can be found here:
http://www.alexconner.co.uk/gallery/explore.html

JS Nav menu
On the menu in the side bar I want the sub menu to be closed as you first enter the page, but again can not get it to work.

Many thanks,

Alex

Comment: Your link shows this: "The document name you requested (/index.php) could not be found on this server." If it works for you, you may want to check your permissions.